# Handling concurrent connections in SiganlR

Tags: notifications, signalr, publish-subscribe, signalr-hub, signalr-backplane

I am using .Net framework 4.5.2 and I will start to make a notification system that send notifications  from web application into users that are connected from windows forms desktop application .

after investigations i found that the suitable solution is using signalR as it supports filtering the notification  before sending it to the connected clients .

but my concern here is that :
when i created my HUB class in the web application , i implemented the method OnConnected that will detect any client who is connected to the server to recieve the notifications , i thought about collecting the connected users in dictionary (in memory) i know it is a solution that couldn't be implemented in the production as this is not reliable to set the connected users in a memory variable (dictionary) . In my case the number of connected users may be 20,000
or over and it may get larger in future . I need to know the best way to track all connected users and at the same time the bets way to handle the concurrent requests without having any scalability issues . I am new in this and i have to make my decision very fast please.

I also need to know in what is the usage of OnReconnect method which can be overidden in the hub class .

I need also to know how to handle the connection to not being lost in case if the iis restarts the internet application for any reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mapping connections to users](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections) can be done in multiple ways, depending on what you want to achieve:

**[In memory storage](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/broadcast-real-time-sql-data-using-signalr/)**:
Best way to do that is by using a [concurrent dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997369(v=vs.110).aspx). This will allow thread safe operations, but, as you said, not the best solution for massive number of connections.

**[Permanent external storage](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections#database)**
Keep your mapping in a database.
**The good part:** the mapping is available across multiple web servers
**The bad part:** a lot of stress on the database and a lot of cleanup necessary

**[Single-User Groups](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections#groups)**
Create one group for each user. This is the most simple and practical solution.

**The good part:**
~ really easy to use and implement
~ SignalR is smart enough to remove the connection from the group when disconnected
~ groups are deleted when you remove the last connection
~ if you use Identity, you can store the unique group name as a claim [[1]](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.ro/2013/12/using-claims-in-aspnet-identity.html) [[2]](http://bitoftech.net/2015/03/31/asp-net-web-api-claims-authorization-with-asp-net-identity-2-1/) and get it inside your hub  with something like:

```
public static class IdentityExtensions
{
    public static string GetSignalRUniqueGroup(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        var claimsIdentity = identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        var claim = claimsIdentity?.FindFirst("uniqueSignalRGroup");
        if (claim == null) return null;

        try
        {
            return claim.Value;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**The** (not really that) **bad part:** you have to be careful with what user joins what group. **!DO NOT!** implement the join group functionality on the client side. Instead, use OnConnected and OnReconnected to add the connection to the group

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    string userGroup = Context.User.Identity.GetSignalRUniqueGroup();
    if(userGroup != null) 
    {
        Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, userGroup);
    }

    return base.OnConnected();
}

public override Task OnReconnected()
{
    string userGroup = Context.User.Identity.GetSignalRUniqueGroup();
    if(userGroup != null) 
    {
        Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, userGroup);
    }       
    return base.OnReconnected();
}

public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
{
    //You should not manually remove the user from the group when the user disconnects. 
    //This action is automatically performed by the SignalR framework.
    return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
}
```

For other question, you can read this:
[Understanding and Handling Connection Lifetime Events in SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events)